# ng-checked with ng-change is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, switch-statement, toggle

Here is my angularjs code

```
<label class="switch">
    <input
    type="checkbox"  
    ng-model="question.questionId" 
    ng-change="questionStatusChange(question.questionId,!question.active)" 
    ng-checked="question.active" >
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

`ng-change` is triggering fine from **unchecked** to **checked** state 
But
`ng-change="questionStatusChange(question.questionId,!question.active)"`  is not working from **checked** to **unchecked** state.

I am trying to enable or disable a table record.

```
$scope.questionStatusChange = function(questionId,status) {
console.log(status);
}
```

I am using this toggle:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: ng-checked OR ng-model. For ng-model you can add ng-change. Never use both on same input.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov at initial loop I want it to be as "checked/unchecked" based on the value, for that reason I used ng-checked.  can you please give the code example.

Comment: Why are you binding an `id` to a checkbox with `ng-model="question.questionId"`? It seems to me like that should be somewhere else in the html, like at a `<label>`

Comment: i dont need ng-model but with ng change is not working without that thats the reason i wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `ng-model` and `ng-checked` are not meant to be used together.

You should be able to just use `ng-model`, and tie it to a `boolean` property on your model. Remove `ng-checked` from your html and just use `ng-model`.

**EDIT:** Below is shown how to use `ng-repeat` to create a list of `<input>` where each section has it's own object within `$scope.questions[]`. Once that's done, you can use `ng-model` and bind it to `questions[i].active` directly.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

var MyController = function($scope) {

  $scope.questions = [{
    questionId: 1,
    active: false,
    questionText: "First question"
  }, {
    questionId: 2,
    active: true,
    questionText: "Second question"
  }];
  $scope.questionStatusChange = function(currentQuestion) {
    //currentQuestion.active = !currentQuestion.active;
    console.log("Current Question Text: " + currentQuestion.questionText + "\nIs it clicked? " +  currentQuestion.active);
  }
}

app.controller(MyController, "[$scope, MyController]");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <label class="switch">
        <input
        type="checkbox"  
        ng-model="question.active"
        ng-change="questionStatusChange(question)" />
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add another checkbox which is already checked on initial, on -change it should uncheck

Comment: @Mrworldwide I've updated my answer.

Comment: can you see my answer once its working fine in the fiddle but in my scenario on initial its not working but when i change its working as expected, is there any other method to get checked on initial load.?